# What is the URL option to display a Mobile XPage App with iPhone theme?

Tags: xpages

When I load an xpages mobile application into desktop safari it displays the app with the default theming for an Android device.  What do you need to do to get it to use the default iPhone theming?

I thought you needed add something like &iPhone=1 to the end of the url, but that's not working.

Thank you.

Comment: ...and don't forget the the tutorial too - http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Mobile_Controls_Tutorial_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [Mobile Controls tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Mobile_Controls_Tutorial_):

> A browser platform query string parameter is available for developers
>   to force the browser to takes precedence over one another. Just add
>   '?platform=iphone' or '?platform=android' to the URL and this will
>   force the correct theme for XPages mobile pages that match against the
>   xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix property.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to enable the Develop menu (Edit - Preferences, then on Advanced tab tick **Show Develop menu in menu bar**. Then from the Develop menu you can change the user agent or set your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sample application for the Extension Library from openntf.org. Go to the "Mobile" tab where you can "extract" the urls to show as iPhone, Android and BlackBerry.

With just a few changes you can add a url as a parameter to this application to show your own mobile app in the same context ;-)  I use that for demo purposes.

/John