# Can't get iOS css to load when developing in Safari for Mac

Tags: css, mobile-safari, xpages

My iOS app has some web code in a Domino Database. I am using Xpages to load the web pages. When I run the app on the simulator or an actual device, the iOS specific CSS is applied. When I run the code in a desktop version of Safari, Chrome, or Firefox and change the user agent to Safari Mobile, the android specific code is getting loaded. I am baffled why this is happening.

Comment: Try this answer to force the iOS CSS to load: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9896115/785061

Comment: I've found this to be the most reliable user agent switcher mechanism, in Chrome -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf?hl=en

Comment: Brian, this chrome extension did not work. Per, I tried that. It partly worked. It shows the default theme for iPhone, but it doesn't apply my custom CSS code, and I do not understand why. I made a small css file and added a few changes to make the app look more like iOS7. On the simulator and on the iPhone this css is applied but not in any desktop browser and I do not understand why not. In fact, my custom css file is not even loaded when I use the platform parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Different user agents in some browsers don't actually pass the right values across. I've seen what you're describing before. Server-side you can access the user agent via SSJS / Java. It's worth logging out the values to see how they differ for actual device and desktop browser.

In 9.0.1 Xsp Properties you can use "Debug user agent" setting to specify iOS or Android user agent. That might help your development.

Comment: Paul, I was very excited when I read about the Debug User Agent property. Set it to iOS - no change. Emptied Cache. No change. Closed Designer and Client. No change. Switched Browser - no change. Sometimes Xpages is incredibly frustrating.